# Why is the data not updating when I update it on mounted()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, path

I want to change the fill value when the string `subtitleURL` isn't an empty string. I change the `subtitleURL` value when one is provided, and it seems to `console.log` just fine in the `mounted` method.

```html
<template>
  <button class="glottis_button" @click="clickTest">
    <svg
      width="18"
      height="20"
      viewBox="0 0 18 20"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M17.42 16.03C17.42 16.65 17.31 17.11 17.09 17.41C16.87 17.71 16.52 18 16.04 18.28C15.76 18.44 15.41 18.6 14.99 18.76C14.57 18.9 14.11 19.02 13.61 19.12C13.11 19.24 12.58 19.33 12.02 19.39C11.48 19.45 10.94 19.48 10.4 19.48C8.96 19.48 7.61 19.29 6.35 18.91C5.09 18.51 3.99 17.92 3.05 17.14C2.13 16.34 1.4 15.35 0.86 14.17C0.32 12.99 0.05 11.62 0.05 10.06C0.05 8.42 0.34 6.99 0.92 5.77C1.52 4.55 2.3 3.54 3.26 2.74C4.24 1.92 5.35 1.31 6.59 0.909999C7.85 0.509999 9.14 0.309999 10.46 0.309999C12.36 0.309999 13.86 0.619999 14.96 1.24C16.08 1.84 16.64 2.63 16.64 3.61C16.64 4.13 16.51 4.58 16.25 4.96C15.99 5.34 15.69 5.64 15.35 5.86C14.85 5.56 14.22 5.27 13.46 4.99C12.72 4.69 11.88 4.54 10.94 4.54C9.26 4.54 7.92 5.02 6.92 5.98C5.94 6.94 5.45 8.27 5.45 9.97C5.45 10.89 5.58 11.69 5.84 12.37C6.12 13.03 6.49 13.58 6.95 14.02C7.41 14.44 7.94 14.76 8.54 14.98C9.14 15.18 9.78 15.28 10.46 15.28C10.9 15.28 11.29 15.24 11.63 15.16C11.97 15.08 12.23 14.99 12.41 14.89V12.07H9.2C9.08 11.85 8.96 11.56 8.84 11.2C8.74 10.84 8.69 10.46 8.69 10.06C8.69 9.34 8.85 8.82 9.17 8.5C9.51 8.18 9.94 8.02 10.46 8.02H15.53C16.13 8.02 16.59 8.19 16.91 8.53C17.25 8.85 17.42 9.31 17.42 9.91V16.03Z"
        :fill="computedFill"
      />
      
    </svg>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GlottisRecorder",
  data() {
    return {
      subtitleURL: "",
      subtitleArray: [],
      clicked: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {

    clickTest: function () {
      console.log(this.subtitleURL)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(async function (
      message,
      sender,
      sendResponse
    ) {
      if (
        message.tabURL === document.URL &&
        this.subtitleURL !== message.subtitleURL
      ) {
        console.log("MESSAGE useeffect", message, sender);
        this.subtitleURL = message.subtitleURL;
        console.log(this.subtitleURL)

      }
    });
  },
  computed: {
    computedFill: function () {
    console.log(this.subtitleArray.length < 1 ? "#fff" : this.clicked === false ? "#1eb4d4" : "#9ef7b9")
      return this.subtitleURL === "" ? "#fff" : this.clicked === false ? "#1eb4d4" : "#9ef7b9";
    },
  }
  
  

};
</script>
```

It prints out the correct value when `this.subtitleValue` is console.logged, but when I click the button, it still has the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is installed with a regular function, so `this` is not actually your Vue component instance.

Switch to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to automatically capture the correct context:

```js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  this.subtitleURL = message.subtitleURL;
})
```